# Bloomberg tick data timezone offset

Tags: time-series, bloomberg, tick-data

I am using python to access the Bloomberg Desktop API and am running into issues with the timezone conversion for their tick data.

The data they deliver is supposed to be UTC but there is something strange going on where some data seems to be offset by a day. See the below conversation for details-- I have tried this but it doesnt seem to be working. I haven't been able to find a pattern in the offset so far:

> Hi *******,
>
> So the offset comes in either positive or negative depending on
>   whether or not GMT is ahead or behind the exchange time zone. So in
>   that sense, I would always grab the hour from the API, sum that with
>   the offset, if we're > 24 hours then add a day and modulo 24 - else if
>   we're < 24 hours, I would take that negative number and add it to 24,
>   and subtract a day.
>
> Something along those lines should do the trick here.
>
> Please reach out with H#******* with any questions - take care,
>
> Bloomberg Help
>
> For further help: Press the  key twice. Reference H#******* to
>   continue this inquiry.
>
> ---
>
> *******@bloomberg.net
>
> Your question was: Re:H#****** Adjusting GMT to local  exchange
>   time
>
> How about this:
>
> Take GMT timestamp returned by API, take the hour, subtract the
>   offset....if the result is less than 0, need to adjust the date
>   forward by one after converting to EST? Does that sound right?
>
> From: HELP DESK (BLOOMBERG) At: May 11 2015 11:21:18 Subject:
>   Re:H#******** Adjusting GMT to local  exchange time
>
> Hi *******,
>
> Following up on our conversation from Friday. Ultimately what we'll
>   need to do is pull in the offset with the TIME_ZONE_NUM field, and add
>   some logic to your code to adjust for the fact that we may go over 24
>   hours here.
>
> One way to do that would be by taking the GMT + offset modulo 24 to
>   get the hour on the next day - then incorporate the fact that we will
>   need to adjust the day forward as well.
>
> Please reach out with h#******** with any further questions here.
>
> Have a good one,
>
> Bloomberg Help
>
> For further help: Press the  key twice. Reference H#******** to
>   continue this inquiry.
>
> ---
>
> Your question was: I am getting API TickData for 8035 JP
>   Equity....something seems be wierd with the timezone conversion. For
>   example...I am looking at a trade in my Terminal at 23:00:07 on
>   01/08/15 [600 shares @ 8670] EST....when I pull the same trade through
>   teh IntraDayTick API function the trade is reported as 04:00:07 on
>   01/08/15 (THIS IS UTC/GMT). However converting this to EST would be
>   23:00:07 on 01/07/15, not 01/08/15....what is going on?

Wondering if anyone has had a similar issue / has solved this? Seems strange to me that this is not clear.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the full example of the problem:

In the Terminal:

```
8035 JP Equity QR:

FROM: 23:00:07 01/08/2015
TO: 23:00:07 01/08/2015
```

Returns Trade:

```
Time: 23:00:07, Size: 600, Price: 8670
```

The Date/Time here is **`EST 23:00:07 01/08/2015`**

The same trade via API `IntradayTickRequest`:

```
tickData = {TIME = 2015-01-08T04:00:07.000
    TYPE = TRADE
    VALUE = 8670.000000
    SIZE = 600}
```

The Date/Time here is `UTC 04:00:07 01/08/2015`, which converted (using http://www.timezoneconverter.com/) is **`ETC 23:00:07 01/07/2015`**

So the Terminal and API are reporting different days for certain trades, I am looking for some sort of rule to standardize the data.

Comment: Yes it's a bit of a mess - even looking at QR/QRM sometimes gives weird results...

Comment: Have you found a straightforward rule for dealing with this? The solution they gave me doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No I'm afraid.. If I do find something I'll let you know, but won't be soon... Maybe somebody else has an answer.

Comment: Ok...will spend some time over the next week trying to figure this out...will post if I find something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the Bloomberg Terminal `QR` function, when adjusting the timezone from Exchange/UTC to your timezone, will convert the time but not the day.

**Trades displayed via `IntradayTickRequest` API are correct in UTC time, trades displayed via Bloomberg Terminal `QR` may be incorrect due to failure to adjust the stated date for timezone adjustments.**

Comment: Wow that's scary - thanks for sharing your results.

Comment: "will convert the time but not the day"
Has it been improved/changed since then? I can't say I have issues with the tickers I'm using, but I would like to be sure I have it all under control..

Answer (score 0):

"some data is offset by a day": you don't give enough detail about what security/data and what time is involved.

This may have to do with the difference between the calendar date and the trading session date.  For example S&P futures begin trading at 6pm new york time on Sunday. However that is considered part of the monday session. So you have to be clear about the actual date and the trading session date. There is trading on Sunday for the Monday business date.

Also, don't talk only to the general Bloomberg help desk, try to reach an API specialist.

HTH

Comment: I added an update to my post, hope that explains what I am confused....I am trying to reconcile my program's data with the Terminal